# multiple routes in Nodejs with express framework?

Tags: node.js, express

My requests have to be sent to these addresses:

- **/students** that has to respond all students.
- **/students/123** that has to respond a student with id = 123.

my code in index.js that routes requests into studentRouter.js is:

```
const studentRouter = require("./routes/studentRouter");
app.use('/students', studentRouter);
```

and my code in Node.js with express framework in the file named studentRouter.js is:

```
studentRouter
.route("/")
.all((req, res, next) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    next();
 })
.get((req, res, next) => {
    res.end("will send all the students!");
 });

 studentRouter
   .route("/:studentId")
   .get((req, res, next) => {
        res.end("will send student " + req.params.studentId);
  });
```

How to change this code and use just one studentRouter not two?

Answer (score 0):

In studentRouter you could do:

```
const students = express.Router()

students.get('/',(req,res) => {
  res.status(200).end('Send all students')
})

students.get('/:studentID',(req,res) => {
  res.status(200).end(`Send student ${req.params.studentID}`)
})

module.exports = students
```

Index.js will be the same.